# "Hello World" application on Java JAX-WS

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, web-services, jax-ws

I have a question ... 
I have an implementation of a simple "Hello World" application on Java JAX-WS:

I did not get access to the methods, specifically "getHelloWorldAsString". 
I tried jquery and plugin "jquery.soap".
How can I call a method from JavaScript?
Can you give me an example? Or what do I change in Java code?

**ITest.java File:**

```
package ru.ntcsiz.searcher.search.test;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;

//Service Endpoint Interface
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public interface ITest {

    @WebMethod String getHelloWorldAsString(String name);

}
```

**TestClass.java:**

```
package ru.ntcsiz.searcher.search.test;

import javax.jws.WebService;

//Service Implementation
@WebService(endpointInterface = "ru.ntcsiz.searcher.search.test.ITest")
public class TestClass implements ITest {

    @Override
    public String getHelloWorldAsString(String name) {
    return "Hello World! It's works! " + name;
    }
}
```

**TestClassPublisher.java:**

```
package ru.ntcsiz.searcher.search.test;

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

public class TestClassPublisher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:9999/ws/test", new TestClass());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your WSDL and generate a javascript client using apache cxf framework. Details are mentioned in below link

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-javascript.html